# How can you consume a distant rest api using gwt?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gwt

I have a couple of sipring boot restfull APIs, that I want to communicate with, from a GWT based front-end. I've looked a bit on the Internet and found the RestyGWT framework, but as far as I've seen, all the documentation available is for using the embeded GWT server as a restfull API. 
Can anyone please direct me to a usefull tutorial that I can follow.

### Thanks to all.

I actually found a way to GET data through JsonPRequestBuilder, the problem now resides in POSTing data in json format.

Comment: See http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

```
final RequestBuilder reqBuilder = new RequestBuilder(httpMethod, url);
final Request request = reqBuilder.sendRequest(requestData, new RequestCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response)
    {
       GWT.log(response.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception)
    {
    }
}
```

httpMethod is something from com.google.gwt.http.client.Method like Method.GET

request is a String in which you pass the json.

response.getText will display the json.

To convert from object to json I would suggest to look at https://github.com/nmorel/gwt-jackson or https://github.com/vegegoku/gwt-jackson-apt  (first one is older and has more features, second one is newer and better suited for future (GWT 3.0) but maybe has some features missing).

Comment: Thanks I also found this to be working well
`JsonpRequestBuilder jsonp = new .requestObject("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", new AsyncCallback<JsArray<Post>>() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                Window.alert(arg0.getMessage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JsArray<Post> psts) {
                Post pst = psts.get(0);
                Window.alert(pst.getBody());
            }
        });`